# How to clear the data from roRegistrysection Roku in developer mode

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am in between developing an roku app, which needs me me save and clear a key d. I am able to do it using roRegistrySection however when I delete the channel, still that key present which should not if I go through the documents which is below

[Roku Documentation](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/roRegistry)

Please advice me how to do it.

Comment: Is not there anyone with Roku specialization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have another app signed with the same developer key on the very same Roku box. Re-read the documentation page you linked to - registry is not unique/isolated "per app" but per "developer ID" - in this way two apps can share a registry if they want to (can be useful at times). And the registry storage will be cleared only when the last such app is deleted.

If this is not a "public" or "private" channel but a "side-loaded" (dev, development channel), you may possibly have to restart Roku for the registry to 
clear.

Answer (score 2):

I use a simple toolbox function to clear the registry during development. Much faster and easier than uninstalling and restarting.

```
sub DeleteRegistry()
    print "Starting Delete Registry"
    Registry = CreateObject("roRegistry")
    i = 0
    for each section in Registry.GetSectionList()
        RegistrySection = CreateObject("roRegistrySection", section)
        for each key in RegistrySection.GetKeyList()
            i = i+1
            print "Deleting " section + ":" key
            RegistrySection.Delete(key)
        end for
        RegistrySection.flush()
    end for
    print i.toStr() " Registry Keys Deleted"
end sub
```

I also have a similar one for viewing the registry.

Comment: When to call this as I don't have any explicit action like sign out?

Comment: I only call it when I want to clear the registry; not as a part of normal operation. So I either have a dev app that is nothing but this, or I call it from the debug window.

If you aren't intending the registry data to live past the closing of the app; then you probably don't need the registry. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Saty if you wanted to clear when you sign out - maybe the registry is NOT what you should be using?  The registry is for persisting data across app restarts (and between apps of same dev as noted above)